# The literal format of format=" %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

Tags: python, logging

I am learning to utilize `logging` rather than `print` to debug my code:

```
In [89]: logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
In [90]: logging.debug("Some debugging details.")
 2018-08-28 16:41:15,371 - DEBUG - Some debugging details.
```

I tried to rewrite the format as literal format,

```
In [5]: logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=f" {(asctime)} - {(levelname)} - {(message)}")
NameError: name 'asctime' is not defined
```

or

```
In [5]: logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=f" {(asctime)} - {(levelname)} - {(message)}")
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
In [6]: logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=f" {(asctime)s} - {(levelname)s} - {(message)s}")
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    ((asctime)s)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible to write a literal format of `format=" %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't possible because the placeholder names in the logging format are interpreted by the `logging` module, while the expressions in the f-string are interpreted by the Python compiler itself, which is unaware of the meaning of the placeholder names understood only by the `logging` module.